# Не работает ReadMore.JS

Tags: javascript

я уже и так его и так, но не работает readmore.js 
вот [пример страницы](https://mycrimea.online/places/ego-studio/) на которой размещен код.

вот сам код:

```
<script src="https://mycrimea.online/js/rm.js"></script>
     <script>
    jQuery('#article').readmore({
        maxHeight: 100,
        moreLink: '<a href="#" class="open-txt"><span>Читать полностью</span></a>',
        lessLink: '<a href="#" class="open-txt"><span>Свернуть</span></a>'
    });
  </script>         
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="article"><?php the_content(); ?></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо разместите свой код :

```
 <script>
jQuery('#article').readmore({
    maxHeight: 100,
    moreLink: '<a href="#" class="open-txt"><span>Читать полностью</span></a>',
    lessLink: '<a href="#" class="open-txt"><span>Свернуть</span></a>'
});
```

внизу страницы. Или оберните в функцию `$(window).load(function() {});`

Comment: проблема решилась, спасибо большое!!!